# Recover Wordpress from unbootable Ubuntu box

Tags: wordpress, ubuntu

After rebooting a Wordpress Dev machine (Ubuntu Desktop), does not boot at all.
I can ping the machine, but cannot access it using SSH. I recon the SSH Daemon doesn't start properly.
Is there a way of recovering the Wordpress site from a dead machine? I have access to the filesystem by attaching it to another machine.

Comment: I suggest you ask this question on https://askubuntu.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depend on your Linux architecture, but you can certainly copy the files for your Wordpress installation. Usually files are in /var/www/....

Additionnaly you need to backup your database, if you have no means to access it throught SSH, you cannot use the SQL dump capability. You can try recovering raw database files wich are usually under /var/lib/*sql (for PostGreSQL database this is /var/lib/pgsql or /var/lib/mysql for MySQL database).

Once your database is backuped you need to use the exact same SQL engine and copy the files to the new database folder (be extr cautious with files permissions).

Comment: If your site was running backups you may luck out and find a backed-up `.sql` file somewhere in the WordPress installation's files. You could restore your database from that.  If your site was not running backups, well, live and learn.